# How to send data to php after validating information on a javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I heard of Ajax/XMLhttprequest but im not quite sure if thats what I need to transfer the data from a javascript variable to php.

The webpage is basicly a contact us page, where customers enter they information plus email, javascript check whether input was enter and validates if email has a @. if everything is fine then customers will be able to submit the form and an email should be delivery to me.

I got two things working, 1 I can get the php file to send an email to me but then I would have to ignore the javascript validation. 2 I can get javacript validation working but then php file wont work as I cant transfer the data. I know javascript execute in the client side and php in the server side, which is why i think i need to validate information in the client side before sending information to server.

HTML

```
       <form id="uDF" method="post" onsubmit="submitValidation()">
            <input name="uDFName" type="text" id="fName" placeholder="Name"><br>
            <input name="uDFNumber" type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Mobile/Phone Line"><br>
            <input name="uDFEmail" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
            <input name="uDFSubject" type="text" id="subject" placeholder="Subject"><br>
            <textarea name="uDFMessage" placeholder="Message......"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" name="uDFButton" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit" id="test">
        </form>
```

Javascript

```
function submitValidation(){
var data = [document.forms ["uDF"] ["uDFName"].value, document.forms ["uDF"] ["uDFNumber"].value,
document.forms ["uDF"] ["uDFEmail"].value, document.forms ["uDF"] ["uDFSubject"].value,
document.forms ["uDF"] ["uDFMessage"].value,]

var char = ''; // variable used to check whether email has @
var x;
var isEmail = false;
var isNotEmpty = false;

//for loop checks email for @ char
for(x = 0; x<data[2].length;x++)
{
    char = data[2].charAt(x);
    if(char === "@"){
        isEmail = true;
        break;
    }
}

var i;

//for loop check if data is collected
for(i=0;i < 5;i++){
    if(data[i] === ""){
        isNotEmpty = false;
    }else{
        isNotEmpty = true;
    }
}
if(isEmail === true && isNotEmpty === true)
{
    THIS IS WHERE I SHOULD TRANSFER THE DATA TO PHP
}else if (!isNotEmpty){
    alert('Empty fields');
}else if(!isEmail){
    alert("Please enter valid email!");
}
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
$uDFName = $_POST['uDFName'];
$uDFNumber = $_POST['uDFNumber'];
$uDFEmail = $_POST['uDFEmail'];
$uDFSubject = $_POST['uDFSubject'];
$uDFMessage = $uDFName . "\r\n" . $uDFNumber . "\r\n" . "";

// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use 
wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
mail($uDFEmail, $uDFSubject, $uDFMessage);
```

PHP works if I put it on the form as action=("mail.php) but then ofcourse no validation will be done.

Comment: you can submit form using `jQuery` or `JavaScript` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your validation finished

You can try like this

It will work like this.

After validation it will call external `php` file. it will send your all `input type` form data in that `php` file with this `$('#yourform').serialize()`.

and you can get that `input form data` in your `php` file like this `$name = $_POST['name'];`

This will work same as the conventional php `GET` and `POST` but here concept is without page loading.

Hope you can understand Now.

```
function submitValidation(){ 

var data = [document.forms ["uDF"] ["uDFName"].value, document.forms ["uDF"] ["uDFNumber"].value, document.forms ["uDF"] ["uDFEmail"].value, document.forms ["uDF"] ["uDFSubject"].value, document.forms ["uDF"] ["uDFMessage"].value,];

var char = ''; // variable used to check whether email has @
var x;
var isEmail = false;
var isNotEmpty = false;

//for loop checks email for @ char
for(x = 0; x<data[2].length;x++)
{
    char = data[2].charAt(x);
    if(char === "@"){
        isEmail = true;
        break;
    }
}

var i;

//for loop check if data is collected
for(i=0;i < 5;i++){
    if(data[i] === ""){
        isNotEmpty = false;
    }else{
        isNotEmpty = true;
    }
}
if(isEmail === true && isNotEmpty === true)
{
    THIS IS WHERE I SHOULD TRANSFER THE DATA TO PHP
     /**** Your Ajax ****/
    $.ajax(
    {
       url: 'yourphpfile.php',
       type: 'post',
       data: $("#uDF").serialize(),
       success: function(response) {
         console.log(response);
       }
    });
   return false;


}else if (!isNotEmpty){
    alert('Empty fields');
    return false;
}else if(!isEmail){
    alert("Please enter valid email!");
    return false;
}



}
```

Comment: Could you please go in more detail what the code does?

Comment: yes I understood first time where to put it. I just meant go in more detail on what its actually does. but thanks I will try it out and find out.

Comment: @Luke oh.. ok let me make you understand. let me edit my answer hope you will get it

Comment: @Luke i just edited answer. hope you can understand with that. And if you get it than please accept answer it will helps me too. :)

Comment: Cheers thanks I think I got it :) I accepted the answer too. if you can like my question that would be nice too. but it might be too stupid of a question haha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147684/discussion-between-nirav-joshi-and-luke).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(isEmail === true && isNotEmpty === true)
{
 //Put below code here
}
```

ajax request to submit form

```
$.ajax({
  type:'post', //method may be get or post to send data
  url:'mail.php', //file name where you will recieve data to precess
  data:$('#uDF').serialize(), //serialize the form data
  success:function(){ //executes when mail.php file found
    //Your success message
  },
  error:function(){ //otherwise error
    //error message
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it. data:('#.serialize'(), could you go in more detail what does that line does? does that means once I call that function all the variables data would be transferred to the right variables in php? I cant quite understand

Comment: The `serialize()` method creates a URL encoded text string by serializing form values.
It means if you have a `input` field in your form with the name attribute of `abc` like `<input name="abc" value="ABC" />` and when you use `serialize()` method it will be look like this
`abc=ABC`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I spend yesterday full day trying to get this working but I think I got an idea now :)